# psycopg2 install mutliple versions of python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-10.04

I have two version of python.
I would like to install psycopg2 for python2.5

How can I run sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 so it installs it for python2.5 and not python2.6 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ubuntu-10.04 package `python-psycopg2` is designed to work with the default python2.6 installation.

To install psycopg2 for python2.5, [download the psycopg source](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/) and use

```
python2.5 setup.py install
```

to install it. (Note the call to `python2.5`).

Comment: That's generally true for any Python package. The disto will typically have a pre-built package for only the "official" Python in their current build system. If you want another version you'll have to package it yourself, or install from source.